# How to test android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, adb

I'd like to be able to test the BroadcastReceiver for MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED.

Can I accomplish this with an adb command?

Does the emulator accomplish this when I launch an app from the IDE (Android studio)?

Comment: I published an update to my app and, after the upgrade, the code for this handler was executed. in case anyone was wondering when precisely the code is run.

Answer (score 15):

`am broadcast -a android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED`

Comment: does this send the intent to all apps? or just my app under test

Comment: it sends it to all apps by default. you can specify the receiver using `-n` parameter

Comment: ok, yes, that's it. for the -n option, I specified <package name>/<receiver name> where <package name> is the 'package' attribute from the manifest XML element, and <receiver name> is the 'android:name' attribute from the receiver element that handles that intent. still unclear on which MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED code is executed: the old app code and the new app code that was replaced

Comment: I want to warn people, be careful when using this command. I ran this on my phone and it ended up being stuck in demo mode because this calls the intent on ALL apps. Use the `-n` parameter to avoid this as @AlexP. mentioned.

Comment: The full command is `adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED`

Comment: @Prem What ist the "demo mode" of an Android phone? Why should it be a problem if any app "thinks" it was updated? It should just do what it does after an update if it's supoosed to do something then. I don't understand the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately the previously proposed solution is not supported on Android 7.0+ because only the system is allowed to broadcast it.

However the intent can be stimulated by `adb install -r` command when side loading the app.

I don't take credit for this answer as [it has been submitted in another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54212643/16823577).