# Android: Broadcast ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED never received

Tags: android, android-studio, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

My app runs a service which is terminated when the device reboots or the app is reinstalled (updated).  I've added two broadcast receivers to catch those events - BOOT_COMPLETED and ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED.

The ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED receiver just doesn't seem to work. Here's what I have:

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <receiver android:name=".RebootReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name=".ReInstallReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

RebootReceiver:

```
public class RebootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Logg.d("Reboot completed. Restarting service");
        context.startService(new Intent(context, MyService.class));
    }
}
```

ReInstallReceiver:

```
public class ReInstallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Logg.d("App Upgraded or Reinstalled. Restarting service");
        context.startService(new Intent(context, MyService.class));
    }
}
```

Running minSdk=16; Testing on Galaxy S3 running KitKat. Testing success by checking if my service is running in Settings/Applications, which it does on reboot, but not reinstall.

I've taken into account notes from the following, which say that in Android Studio 1.0+, manifest mergers mean I can't combine two receivers into one class.  See [ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED not received](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12666734/action-my-package-replaced-not-received) and [Android manifest merger fails for receivers with same name but different content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24447663/android-manifest-merger-fails-for-receivers-with-same-name-but-different-content)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You probably figured this out already, but your action name in the manifest is wrong, instead of:

```
android.intent.action.ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED
```

it should be

```
android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED
```

You can also manually trigger the receiver using `adb shell` for testing purposes:

```
adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED -n com.example.myapp/.ReInstallReceiver
```

Comment: can't emulate this intent using adb command on Android 7 Nougat, seems that now it's in the list of sensitive intents: "java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED". Works perfectly on Kit-Kat 4.4 though, even without adb command it calls my breakpoint in receiver every time I start the app in Android Studio

Answer (score 16):

I wanted to update this thread with a new answer, as I have found no posts that offer an updated solution for Android 7.0+ where this `Intent` is now protected.

Go to `Build -> Build APK`, and note the location that the .apk is stored.

Then, run in terminal:

```
adb install -r debugapp.apk
```

This will trigger the `MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED` intent, since newer Android SDKs only allow the system to broadcast it.

Comment: Does this work even if the re-installed APK is identical to the one that was originally installed? Or is it necessary to increment the version code?

Comment: @AlexvonBrandenfels, Version code is only necessary to increment when pushing a signed package to Firebase Test Lab or Google Play, the package replaced flag re-installs the same app while triggering the replacement intent.

Comment: @AlexvonBrandenfels no, i had to manually install the apk using adb using -d (downgrade, add this) option. then you can use the "run app" button in android studio to deploy to emulator and it should trigger MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED.

Answer (score 9):

[image: ACTION EXPLAIN IMAGE]

Take into account that：

1. A new version of your Application
2. You should run adb install -r your new version apk,if you just run
   at Android Studio it won't receive this broadcast

Comment: -1 , I'm testing an app on Android 10, Specifically the app is https://github.com/M66B/NetGuard
It recieves the broadcast even with Android studio install and without new version code.